# java - which exception fits best an Unauthorized HTTP response (401)?

Tags: android, exception, retrofit, unauthorized

In java (Android), is there a standard exception I should throw to signal a 401 Unauthorized response from a server?

Comment: This totally depends on the network tools/library you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was an accepted standard thing, maybe in org.apache.http or such.

Comment: Totally depends on how the HTTP Protocol (which defines error code 401 as being "unauthorized") is handled... Your question cannot be asked without more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

After a few years it seems that the response was 'no there isn't'.